# Two laravel5.1 projects communicate with each other, the receiving party can not get .env file content

Tags: php, laravel, curl, postman

project A request project B;
project A:
database name is db_a;

```
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->get('http://my.b.com/api/login');
dd($curl->response);
```

project B:
database name is db_b;

```
return $_ENV;
```

I find 'vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php' file  print $database and exit; 
use Postman tool print db_b;
use curl print fail database_name db_a;
why?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`config()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values) or `env()` to get value from local `.env` file and pass it to second app.

Comment: thanks, i real question is collection database config error, project A request project B, project B use ORM error: "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project A database_name.table_name' doesn't exist"